# @Slf4j produces `non-static variable org cannot be referenced` if the class has `org` field

Tags: java, slf4j, lombok

Why, if my class has an `org` field, I cannot use `@Slf4j` Lombok log annotation. The following code will produce a compilation error at line #3:

> ***MyClass.java:[3,1] non-static variable org cannot be referenced from a static context***

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
class MyClass {
  String org;

  void printDebug() { log.debug("Org: " + org); }
}
```

Lombok documentation ([projectlombok.org/features/log](https://projectlombok.org/features/log)) claims it adds a single `log` field. Why it conflicts with `org`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you, in IntelliJ, do right-click -> Refactor -> Delombok -> @Log (and friends), you'll see the generated fields initialization starts with:  `= org.slf4j...`:

```
private static final Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
//                                ^^^ - this is ambiguous
```

and this produces the conflict with your `org` field:

```
String org;
//     ^^^
```

---

Lombok team could work-around this by injecting `import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory`, but they might think the demand for the fix is not so high. This is an opinion of a Lombok contributor:

> *...This is a handicap in the java language that uses the same notation for two completely different concepts. Don't know what could be done in lombok to solve this issue without creating some other issue somewhere else. [[REF](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1400#issuecomment-321885079)]*

---

**SOLUTION**: So, in cases you have `org` field, just replace your:

- `import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;` and
- `@Slf4j` with:

---

```
import static org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger;



  private static final Logger log = getLogger(MyClass.class);
```